# how to stream with ffmpeg with native fps

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, pipe, streaming

i want stream with native (30 fps) file from raw format (using pipe). I have this:

```
./program | ffmpeg -f rawvideo -r 30 -pixel_format bgr24 -video_size 1280x720 -i - -f mpegts -r 30 udp://127.0.0.1:12344
```

and it works. But i olny 17-18 fps on output:

```
Input #0, rawvideo, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 663552 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[24] / 0x18524742), bgr24, 1280x720, 663552 kb/s, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> mpeg2video (native))
Output #0, mpegts, to 'udp://127.0.0.1:1234':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.16.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p, 1280x720, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.19.102 mpeg2video
    Side data:

frame=  208 fps= 17 q=31.0 Lsize=     863kB time=00:00:06.86 bitrate=1029.4kbits/s speed=0.553x
```

what could be the problem?

Comment: What's the receiving speed? `./program | ffmpeg -f rawvideo -r 30 -pixel_format bgr24 -video_size 1280x720 -i - -c copy -f null -`

Comment: actually, i understand what a problem. Without flag `-pixel_format bgr24` ffmpeg stream with 30 fps. But video is corrupt @Gyan

Comment: Which is the accurate source pixel format?

Comment: @Gyan, source video file has yuv420p (ffmpeg information). After my program pixel format is bgr24 and it works correctly, but only 16-18 fps. If I set -pixel_format yuv420p, video will be corrupt, but with 30+ fps

Comment: What's the fps output of my command?

Comment: `Input #0, rawvideo, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 552960 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[24] / 0x18524742), bgr24, 1280x720, 552960 kb/s, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Output #0, null, to 'udp://127.0.0.1:1234':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.16.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[24] / 0x18524742), bgr24, 1280x720, q=2-31, 552960 kb/s, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
frame=  350 fps= 17 q=-1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:14.00 bitrate=N/A speed=0.694x  ` @Gyan

Comment: Right. Your program can't pipe the output fast enough.

Comment: @Gyan, thanks, it have sense.